# Unable to convert PySpark Dataframe to Pandas dataframe with row count > 15M records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to convert a PySpark dataframe to Pandas dataframe using toPandas() function.
However, its failing !

My Pyspark dataframe contains more than 15M records. Does that seems to be problem ?

```
from pyspark.sql import *  
from pyspark.sql.functions import *  
from pyspark.sql.types import *  
import pandas as pd

df = sqlContext.table("schema.table")
df_pd=df.toPandas()
```

Getting the below error :
**An error was encountered:
Invalid status code '400' from http://xyz:1000/sessions/205/statements/2 with error payload: {"msg":"requirement failed: Session isn't active."}**

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark is a distributed processing framework while pandas does all the processing on a single node.

Now when you try to convert a spark dataframe to pandas, it tries to get data from all nodes to single mode and if your memory is not enough to process all the data on a single node it will fail and also it is not recommended.

Why do you even want to convert a spark df to pandas df? I think you can achieve similar capabilities in spark also.

Comment: I am trying to use some pandas and numpy functions which aren't available in spark directly. hence I am converting the dataframe to pandas to perform them effectively.

Comment: If your data size is huge going back to pandas and numpy is not a good option.. You can do the operations using pyspark functions directly.